# UIPageViewController in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uipageviewcontroller

In `PageViewController` I want to add page indicators. When I apply two go the `UIPageVieController DataSource methods`:

```
func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int 

func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
```

The `pageIndicator` appears at the bottom of the `ViewController`, but having a default black background colour, grey tint colour & white current index colour. Also, if I want to position of this `pageIndicator` is fixed. It does not change.

**Here are the screenshots:**

[image: simulator image]

The black page indicator is static.

Answer (score 0):

> but having a default black background colour, grey tint colour & white current index colour.

Use the *appearance proxy* to change the colors. Example:

```
    let proxy = UIPageControl.appearance()
    proxy.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
    proxy.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .red
    proxy.backgroundColor = .yellow
```

> Also, if I want to position of this pageIndicator is fixed. It does not change.

Nothing you can do about that. If you use the built-in page indicator, it is built in. It is where it is. Of course you can supply your own UIPageControl and put it where you want to, but then coordinating it with the page view controller will be completely up to you.